# How to transform leptokurtic distribution to normality?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, kurtosis, qq-plot

Suppose I have a leptokurtic variable that I would like to transform to normality.  What transformations can accomplish this task? I am well aware that transforming data may not always be desirable, but as an academic pursuit, suppose I want to "hammer" the data into normality. Additionally, as you can tell from the plot, all values are strictly positive.

I have tried a variety of transformations (pretty much anything I have seen used before, including $\frac 1 X,\sqrt X,\text{asinh}(X)$, etc.), but none of them work particularly well.  Are there well-known transformations for making leptokurtic distributions more normal?

See the example Normal Q-Q plot below:

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the [probability integral transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform)?  It has been invoked in [a few threads on this site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22probability+integral+transform%22), if you would like to see it in action.

Comment: You need something that works symmetrically on (variable $-$ "middle") while also respecting sign. Nothing that you tried comes close if you don't have a "middle". Use median for "middle" and try cube root of the deviations, remembering to implement cube root as sign(.) * abs(.)^(1/3). No guarantees and very ad hoc, but it should push in the right direction.

Comment: Uh, what makes you call that platykurtic? Unless I missed something, that looks like it's got higher kurtosis than the normal.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: [transformation-to-increase-kurtosis-and-skewness-of-normal-r-v](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43482/).

Comment: @Glen_b I think is right: it's leptokurtic. But both these terms are pretty silly, except in so far as they allow reference to the original cartoon by Student in _Biometrika_. The criterion is kurtosis; values are high or low or (even better) quantified.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely made a mistake about the kurtosis.  I fixed it; thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Why is leptokurtic described as 'thin tailed'? While there's no necessary relationship between thickness of tail and kurtosis, the general tendency is for heavy tails to be associated with kurtosis (e.g. compare $t_6$ with normal, for standardized densities)

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  Nick Cox gets the gold star for the day, I will post a solution based off his idea that works quite nicely.

Comment: can you share the data with us here?

Comment: @GeorgM.Goerg Unfortunately I do not have the original data any more.  I do know it was observed data, not generated from a known distribution.  That being said, Gleb_b had an Answer that generated a good replication using a mixture of two normal distributions.

Comment: @Underminer thanks for the info.  I have also added an answer below that replicated your data more or less.   Glen_b's suggestions with  the mixture of two normals with different scales is another way to model heavy tails; depends on your application I guess and background of the data to see which one makes more sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Credit for this answer goes to @NickCox's suggestion in the comments section of the original question.  He suggested I subtract the median of the data and apply the transformation to the deviations.  For instance, $\text{sign(.)}\cdot\text{abs(.)}^{\frac 1 3}$, with $Y-\text{median}(Y)$ as the argument.

Although the cube root transformation didn't work out well, it turns out the square root and the more obscure three-quarters root work well.

Here was the original kernel density plot corresponding to the Q-Q plot of the leptokurtic variable in the original question:

[image]

---

After applying the square root transformation to the deviations, the Q-Q plot looks like this:

[image]

Better, but it can be closer.

---

Hammering some more, applying the three-quarters root transformation to the deviations gives:

[image]

---

And the final kernel density of this transformed variable looks like this:

[image]

Looks close to me.

Answer (score 14):

I use [heavy tail Lambert W x F distributions](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/aa/909231/) to describe and transform leptokurtic data. See (my) following posts for more details and references:

- [Transformation to increase kurtosis and skewness of normal r.v](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/43482/transformation-to-increase-kurtosis-and-skewness-of-normal-r-v/138814#138814): this shows some illustrations of how the densities vary when varying $\delta$.
- [What's the distribution of these data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33115/whats-the-distribution-of-these-data/47917#47917): an application example of how to use this to estimate model parameters and Gaussianize your data.

Here is a reproducible example using the [**LambertW**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LambertW/index.html) R package.

```
library(LambertW)
set.seed(1)
theta.tmp <- list(beta = c(2000, 400), delta = 0.2)
yy <- rLambertW(n = 100, distname = "normal", 
                theta = theta.tmp)

test_norm(yy)
```

[image: test normality of original data]

```
## $seed
## [1] 267509
## 
## $shapiro.wilk
## 
##  Shapiro-Wilk normality test
## 
## data:  data.test
## W = 1, p-value = 0.008
## 
## 
## $shapiro.francia
## 
##  Shapiro-Francia normality test
## 
## data:  data.test
## W = 1, p-value = 0.003
## 
## 
## $anderson.darling
## 
##  Anderson-Darling normality test
## 
## data:  data
## A = 1, p-value = 0.01
```

The qqplot of `yy` is very close to your qqplot in the original post and the data is indeed slightly leptokurtic with a kurtosis of 5.  Hence your data can be well described by a Lambert W $\times$ Gaussian distribution with input $X \sim N (2000, 400)$ and a tail parameter of $\delta = 0.2$ (which implies that only moments up to order $\leq 5$ exist).

Now back to your question: how to make this leptokurtic data normal again?  Well, we can estimate the parameters of the distribution using MLE (or for methods of moments use `IGMM()`),

```
mod.Lh <- MLE_LambertW(yy, distname = "normal", type = "h")
summary(mod.Lh)

## Call: MLE_LambertW(y = yy, distname = "normal", type = "h")
## Estimation method: MLE
## Input distribution: normal
## 
##  Parameter estimates:
##        Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
## mu     2.05e+03    4.03e+01    50.88   <2e-16 ***
## sigma  3.64e+02    4.36e+01     8.37   <2e-16 ***
## delta  1.64e-01    7.84e-02     2.09    0.037 *  
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## -------------------------------------------------------------- 
## 
## Given these input parameter estimates the moments of the output random variable are 
##   (assuming Gaussian input): 
##  mu_y = 2052; sigma_y = 491; skewness = 0; kurtosis = 13.
```

and then use the *bijective* inverse transformation (based on `W_delta()`) to backtransform the data to the input $X$, which -- by design -- should be very close to a normal.

```
# get_input() handles does the right transformations automatically based on
# estimates in mod.Lh
xx <- get_input(mod.Lh)
test_norm(xx)
```

[image: test normality of Gaussianized data]

```
## $seed
## [1] 218646
## 
## $shapiro.wilk
## 
##  Shapiro-Wilk normality test
## 
## data:  data.test
## W = 1, p-value = 1
## 
## 
## $shapiro.francia
## 
##  Shapiro-Francia normality test
## 
## data:  data.test
## W = 1, p-value = 1
## 
## 
## $anderson.darling
## 
##  Anderson-Darling normality test
## 
## data:  data
## A = 0.1, p-value = 1
```

Voila!

Comment: I'm a fan, and started work on a scikit-learn like version for python: https://github.com/gregversteeg/gaussianize

Comment: Georg is it possible for you to provide a more intuitive explanation of how your transform works?

Comment: @azuric It's based on the inverse transformation of $Z=U \cdot \exp(\delta / 2 \cdot U^2)$ , where $U$ is a standard normal random variable.  W/o going into details (see papers for reference) it should be intuitively clear that for $\delta>0$ the random variable $Z$ has heavy tails .  so all you need to do when you observe heavy tailed data is to find the inverse transformation to get back "normal" data.

Answer (score 8):

In many cases, there may simply be no simple-form monotonic transformation that will produce a close-to-normal result.

For example, imagine that we have a distribution which is a finite mixture of lognormal distributions of various parameters. A log transform would transform any of the components of the mixture to normality, but the mixture of normals in the transformed data leaves you with something that's not normal.

Or there may be relatively nice transform, but not of one of the forms you'd think to try -- if you don't know the distribution of the data, you may not find it. For example, if the data were gamma-distributed, you won't even find the exact transform to normality (which certainly exists) unless I tell you exactly what the distribution is (though you might stumble upon the cube-root transformation that in this case would make it pretty close to normal as long as the shape parameter isn't too small).

There are myriad ways in which the data can look reasonably amenable to being transformed but which doesn't look great on any of a list of obvious transformations.

If you can give us access to the data, it may well be that we can either spot a transformation that does okay -- or that we can show you why you won't find one.

Just from the visual impression there, it looks rather like a mixture of two normals with different scales. There's only a slight hint of asymmetry, which you could easily observe by chance. Here's an example of a sample from a mixture of two normals with common mean - as you see it looks quite a bit like your plot (but other samples may look heavier or lighter tailed - at this sample size there's a lot of variation in the order statistics outside 1 sd either side of the mean).

[image]

In fact here are yours and mine superimposed:

$\quad\quad\quad $[image]

Comment: It certainly does look like a mixture of two normal distributions of different scale, excellent observation.