# Low kurtosis (platykurtic) distribution transform to normal distribution

Tags: r, time-series, normal-distribution, normality-assumption, kurtosis

I use QQ-plot on residuals in time series analysis and find the distribution is not normally distributed, but somehow thin-tail distributed:

[image]

I know that if the residuals are not a normal distribution, the model assumption does not hold and needs to transform the data to normality then fit the model. However, I searched some answers ([how-to-transform-leptokurtic-distribution-to-normality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85687/how-to-transform-leptokurtic-distribution-to-normality)) which are all related to transforming the heavy-tail distributed data to normal distribution.

My question is:
1.Can I use the light-tailed distribution to analyze data even under the normality assumption?
2.Does the heavy-tailed problem more severe than light-tailed problem?

Comment: Whether a normality assumption is important depends on what you are actually doing.

Comment: For most models, such residuals would be considered even *better* than Normally distributed ones!  (I strongly doubt these are real data, though.  Residuals just don't behave like this.)

Comment: Are the data U(0,105)? (Not sure about the upper bound).  Sure looks that way!