# T-test for non normal when N>50?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, t-test, inference, central-limit-theorem

Long ago I learnt that normal distribution was necessary to use a two sample T-test. Today a colleague told me that she learnt that for N>50 normal distribution was not necessary. Is that true?

If true is that because of the central limit theorem?

Comment: Related question with a *very* good answer by Glen_b http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121852/how-to-choose-between-t-test-or-non-parametric-test-e-g-wilcoxon-in-small-sampl

Answer (score 125, accepted):

**Normality assumption of a t-test**

Consider a large population from which you could take many different samples of a particular size. (In a particular study, you generally collect just one of these samples.)

The t-test assumes that the means of the different samples are normally distributed; it does not assume that the population is normally distributed.

By the central limit theorem, means of samples from a population with finite variance approach a normal distribution regardless of the distribution of the population. Rules of thumb say that the sample means are basically normally distributed as long as the sample size is at least 20 or 30. For a t-test to be valid on a sample of smaller size, the population distribution would have to be approximately normal.

The t-test is invalid for small samples from non-normal distributions, but it is valid for large samples from non-normal distributions.

**Small samples from non-normal distributions**

As Michael notes below, sample size needed for the distribution of means to approximate normality depends on the degree of non-normality of the population. For approximately normal distributions, you won't need as large sample as a very non-normal distribution.

Here are some simulations you can run in R to get a feel for this. First, here are a couple of population distributions.

```
curve(dnorm,xlim=c(-4,4)) #Normal
curve(dchisq(x,df=1),xlim=c(0,30)) #Chi-square with 1 degree of freedom
```

Next are some simulations of samples from the population distributions. In each of these lines, "10" is the sample size, "100" is the number of samples and the function after that specifies the population distribution. They produce histograms of the sample means.

```
hist(colMeans(sapply(rep(10,100),rnorm)),xlab='Sample mean',main='')
hist(colMeans(sapply(rep(10,100),rchisq,df=1)),xlab='Sample mean',main='')
```

For a t-test to be valid, these histograms should be normal.

```
require(car)
qqp(colMeans(sapply(rep(10,100),rnorm)),xlab='Sample mean',main='')
qqp(colMeans(sapply(rep(10,100),rchisq,df=1)),xlab='Sample mean',main='')
```

**Utility of a t-test**

I have to note that all of the knowledge I just imparted is somewhat obsolete; now that we have computers, we can do better than t-tests. As Frank notes, you probably want to use [Wilcoxon tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) anywhere you were taught to run a t-test.

Comment: Good explanation (+1). I would add, however, that the sample size needed for the distribution of means to approximate normality depnds on the degree of non-normalness of the population. For large samples there is no reason to prefer a t-test over a permutations test that makes no assumptions about the distributions.

Comment: +1 although, as far as I know, t-test is fairly resistent to moderate deviations from normality. Also, an interesting related discussion: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/normality-testing-essentially-useless

Comment: (+1 to the comments) Good points! My answer was very black-and-white because I don't really know the theory about the greyness in between. I added some simulations that may help address this though.

Comment: good answer, although there is one small detail that you missed: the distribution of the data must have finite variance.  T-test is hopeless for comparing difference in location of two Cauchy distributions (or student with 2 degrees of freedom), not because it is "non-robust", but because for these distributions there is additional relevant information in the sample beyond the means and standard deviations which the t-test throws away.

Comment: But is there really data in reality that has has an underlying infinite variance? I would suspect that this happens only by taking ratios where the value can be arbitarily close to zero. Otherwise I disagree that there is no reason to use the t-test any more; it is so closely based on the effect size that it already remains useful for this purpose. Much more critical the Wilcoxon test tests medians and not means - in some cases this does not matter, in other it might be exactly what you want and in still other it might not be what you want at all.

Comment: In addition to this, t-test also naturally yield confidence intervals for the parameter being investigated. (still upvote because of the two first paragraphs which adress the question directly, I just disagree strongly with the third)

Comment: "But is there really data in reality that has has an underlying infinite variance?"  Certainly there is! Stock returns?

Comment: @Erik: data "in reality" with an infinite variance occurs often! besides, you dont need the variance to be infinite, it is enough that it is "effectively infinite" see my answer to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94402/what-is-the-difference-between-finite-and-infinite-variance/100161#100161

Comment: t-test DOES require normality of the population. That's an assumption needed for the t statistic to have a t-Student distribution. If you don't have a normal population, you can't express the t statistic as a standard normal variable divided by the root of a Chi-squared variable divided by its degrees of freedom. Maybe what you are trying to say is that if some conditions are true, like not too much skewness, or a big sample, the test can still be valid even when the population is not normal.

Comment: I agree with @toneloy -- for the t-test to have a t-distribution does rely on normality. A t-statistic is not just a numerator, it's a ratio of two random variables and the behavior of the denominator (and the dependence between the two) is relevant in determining how the statistic is distributed. I discuss this in the first part of my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/253318/805).

Comment: Hello! Do you have any reference about this statement: "The t-test is invalid for small samples from non-normal distributions, but it is valid for large samples from non-normal distributions"? I wish to read more about it and it'd be very helpful if you could share with me.

Comment: It is plain wrong to say t-test does not assume that population is normally distributed. IT DOES. It is a prevalent question and upon Google search the engine summarizses this answer as its result and maintains that t-test does not assume population to be normally distributed. This is misleading everyone and due corrections are in order

Comment: I believe the conclusion "The t-test is invalid for small samples from non-normal distributions, but it is valid for large samples from non-normal distributions." is prob. wrong. CLT implies, as you write, that the means approach a normal dist., not that the population does.

Comment: @Glen_b I respectfully disagree with you, Milo, toneloy, *et al.*  Mathematically you all are correct but IMHO that misses the point. Insisting on a Normal population to justify and apply the t-test is far too severe and limiting.  As in *all* applications of statistical procedures, one need only establish that the sampling distribution of the t-statistic is likely to be *close enough* to a Student t distribution so as to provide useful, defensible conclusions.

Comment: I don't dispute your point but there's a comment in the answer that I still have an issue with - and that prompted my response. If only the author had instead put it this way.

Comment: I also wanted to point out that this post linked to the Wilcoxon SIGNED RANK test which is only appropriate for PAIRED data. It is analogous to a paired t-test, but it would not be appropriate for a test between two independent groups. The Wilcoxon test for independent sets of data is the Wilcoxon RANK SUM test.

Answer (score 68):

The central limit theorem is less useful than one might think in this context.  First, as someone pointed out already, one does not know if the current sample size is "large enough".  Secondly, the CLT is more about achieving the desired type I error than about type II error.  In other words, the t-test can be uncompetitive power-wise.  That's why the Wilcoxon test is so popular.  If normality holds, it is 95% as efficient as the t-test.  If normality does not hold it can be arbitrarily more efficient than the t-test.

Comment: (+1) Welcome to the site, which I'm glad you've found. I look forward to your participation here.

Comment: (+1) Good point about the Wilcoxon.

Comment: Interesting! Empirically speaking, what do you estimate is a sample size that is 'large-enough' for t-test to be better?

Comment: The power deficiency of the t-test will not be made up for by increasing the sample size, as the Wilcoxon test power will also continue to increase.

Answer (score 24):

See my previous answer to a question on the [robustness of the t-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/robust-t-test-for-mean/1391#1391).

In particular, I recommend playing around with the [onlinestatsbook applet](http://onlinestatbook.com/stat_sim/robustness/index.html).

The image below is based on the following scenario:

- null hypothesis is true
- fairly severe skewness
- same distribution in both groups
- same variance in both groups
- sample size per group 5 (i.e., much less than 50 as per your question)
- I pressed the 10,000 simulations button about 100 times to get up to over one million simulations.

The simulation obtained suggests that instead of getting a 5% Type I errors, I was only getting 4.5% Type I errors.

Whether you consider this robust depends on your perspective.

[image]

Comment: +1 Good points.  The *power* of the t-test with skewed alternatives, though, can degrade severely (to the point where it is essentially zero even for huge effect sizes).

Answer (score 9):

In my experience with just the one-sample t-test, I have found that the *skew* of the distributions is more important than the kurtosis, say. For non-skewed but fat-tailed distributions (a t with 5 degrees of freedom, a Tukey h-distribution with $h=0.24999$, etc), I have found that 40 samples has always been sufficient to get an empirical type I rate near the nominal.  When the distribution is very skewed, however, you may need many many more samples.

For example, suppose you were playing the lottery. With probability $p = 10^{-4}$ you will win 100 thousand dollars, and with probability $1-p$ you will lose one dollar. If you perform a t-test for the null that the mean return is <strike>zero</strike> based on a sample of one thousand draws of this process, I don't think you are going to achieve the nominal type I rate.

**edit**: duh, per @whuber's catch in the comment, the example I gave did not have mean zero, so testing for mean zero has nothing to do with the type I rate.

Because the lottery example often has a sample standard deviation of zero, the t-test chokes. So instead, I give a code example using Goerg's [Lambert W x Gaussian](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LambertW/) distribution. The distribution I use here has a skew of around 1355.

```
#hey look! I'm learning R!
library(LambertW)

Gauss_input = create_LambertW_input("normal", beta=c(0,1))
params = list(delta = c(0), gamma = c(2), alpha = 1)
LW.Gauss = create_LambertW_output(input = Gauss_input, theta = params)
#get the moments of this distribution
moms <- mLambertW(beta=c(0,1),distname=c("normal"),delta = 0,gamma = 2, alpha = 1)

test_ttest <- function(sampsize) {
    samp <- LW.Gauss$rY(params)(n=sampsize)
    tval <- t.test(samp, mu = moms$mean)
    return(tval$p.value)
}

#to replicate randomness
set.seed(1)

pvals <- replicate(1024,test_ttest(50))
#how many rejects at the 0.05 level?
print(sum(pvals < 0.05) / length(pvals))

pvals <- replicate(1024,test_ttest(250))
#how many rejects at the 0.05 level?
print(sum(pvals < 0.05) / length(pvals))

p    vals <- replicate(1024,test_ttest(1000))
#how many rejects at the 0.05 level?
print(sum(pvals < 0.05) / length(pvals))

pvals <- replicate(1024,test_ttest(2000))
#how many rejects at the 0.05 level?
print(sum(pvals < 0.05) / length(pvals))
```

This code gives the empirical reject rate at the nominal 0.05 level for different sample sizes. For sample of size 50, the empirical rate is 0.40 (!); for sample size 250, 0.29; for sample size 1000, 0.21; for sample size 2000, 0.18.  Clearly the one-sample t-test suffers from skew.

Comment: In the example you're discussing the power of the test, not its size.  The null, by the way, appears to be $p=0$, for which the distribution is degenerate (an atom at a single point): that's about as far from normality as one can be!

Answer (score 5):

The central limit theorem establishes (under the required conditions) that the numerator of the t-statistic is asymptotically normal. The t-statistic also has a denominator. To have a t-distribution you'd need the denominator to be independent and square-root-of-a-chi-square-on-its-df.

And we *know* it won't be independent (that characterizes the normal!)

Slutsky's theorem combined with the CLT would give you that the t-statistic is asymptotically normal (but not necessarily at a very useful rate).

We would want a theorem that would establish that the t-statistic is approximately t-distributed when there's non-normality, and how fast it comes in. (Of course, eventually the t- will go close to the normal as well, and in that sense we will often tend to get about the right significance level, at least in sufficiently large samples for all these effects to "work" sufficiently for our individual requirements.)

---

However, more important* than the purported level-robustness of the $t$ (at larger sample sizes) is the effect on its *power*. Note that the asymptotic relative efficiency of the t-test relative to the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney (for example) may be 0 (i.e. as sample sizes become large while effect sizes you want to pick up shrink, you may require vastly larger samples for the t to have the same power as an obvious alternative).

So while the t-test may end up having a nice normal-looking null distribution in many cases if $n$ is large enough, its performance under the null isn't really what people care most about -- it is the performance under the alternative -- and there it may not be so great, if you care about rejecting the null in cases where the effect is not so easy to pick up.

---

* for one thing, there are other ways to control the significance level, such as via a permutation test

Comment: While we may not know if the sample mean and variance are independent, we always know that they are *uncorrelated*.  This is because the sample mean is a function of bivariate sums $x_{i}+x_{j}$, and sample variance is a function of bivariate differences $x_{i}-x_{j}$ (these are called "U statistics") and we have $cov(x_{i}+x_{j},x_{i}-x_{j})=var(x_{i})-var(x_{j})+cov(x_{i},x_{j})-cov(x_{j},x_{i})=0$ as long as the distribution is "homogenous" $var(x_{i})=var(x_{j})$, which is part of the problem statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, the distinction between uncorrelated and independent is relevant if we are to be ending up with a t-distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Central Limit Theorem tells us this is true. So long as you avoid extremely heavy-tailed traits, non-Normality presents no problems in moderate-to-large samples.

Here's a helpful review paper;

http://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev.publhealth.23.100901.140546

The Wilcoxon test (mentioned by others) can have terrible power when the alternative is not a location shift of the original distribution. Furthermore, the way it measures differences between distributions is not transitive.

Comment: Interesting points about the Wilcoxon.  However, the t-test has similar difficulties: it's especially bad at detecting shifts that are accompanied by increased variance.  The bit about transitivity appears to be mainly a curiosity in the present context; it's difficult to see how it's relevant to the original hypothesis test or its interpretation.  (But maybe intransitivity could become important in an ANOVA or multiple comparisons setting.)

Comment: The unequal variance t-test (which is the default in some software) doesn't have the problem with heteroskedasticity.

Comment: Regarding transitivity; reporting the sample means, or differences in means (which is natural using a t-test approach) gives the reader something they can consider when sampling from other populations. The non-transitivity of the Wilcoxon test means that this approach has no such analog; using ranks of data is a very limited approach.

Comment: (1) The Satterthwaite-Welch (unequal variance) test doesn't overcome the power loss I referred to (although it can help a little).  (2) I think you're being extreme in characterizing using ranks as "limited." In his reply, @Frank Harrell was referring to studies showing how the Wilcoxon test maintains high efficiency in many settings: this demonstrates how using the ranks is both effective and *more flexible,* not more limited, compared to t tests.

Comment: (1) No, but it gives the right Type I error rate, in moderate-to-large samples (2) Thanks, but I respectfully disagree. Using t-tests over Wilcoxon makes it much easier to bridge the gap between testing and using confidence intervals. 

If one only wants to do testing, and never looks beyond the two groups in a study, Wilcoxon of course has situations where it works well. But often we don't want to do just testing, and want to help users generalize the results to other situations; the Wilcoxon test is then not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

About the use of Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test as an alternative I recommend the paper [The Wilcoxon-Man-Whitney test under scrutiny](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/24045186_The_Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney_test_under_scrutiny)

As a test of means or medians, the Wilcoxon–Mann–Whitney (WMW) test can be severely nonrobust for deviations from the pure shift model.

These are the recommendation of the authors of the paper:

The rank transformation can alter means, standard deviations, and skewnesses of the two samples differently. The only situation in which the rank transformation is guaranteed to achieve a beneficial effect is when distributions are identical and sample sizes are equal. For deviations from these rather strict assumptions, the effects of the rank transformation on sample moments are unpredictable.
In the simulation study of the paper, the WMW test was compared with the Fligner–Policello test (FP), the Brunner–Munzel test (BM), the two-sample T test (T ), the Welch U test (U), and the Welch U test on ranks (RU). The four rank-based tests (WMW, FP, BM, and RU) performed similarly, although
the BM test was frequently a little better than the others. When the sample sizes were equal, the parametric tests (T and U) were superior to the rank-based tests under the null hypothesis of equal means, but not under the null hypothesis of equal medians. When the sample sizes were unequal, the
BM, RU, and U tests performed best. For several settings, small changes in population properties led to large alterations in the performance of the tests. In summary, the large sample approximate WMW test can be a poor method for comparing the means or medians of two populations, unless the two distributions have equal shapes and equal scales. This problem also seems to apply in various degrees to the exact WMW test, the FP test, the BM test, and the Welch U test on ranks. 
When using the WMW test, the authors recommend that the properties of the ranked samples are thoroughly investigated for signs of skewness and variance
heterogeneity. If such effects are present, the Welch U test is preferable in many situations.