# Which statistical test to look for performance difference in two samples?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am trying to find if there is any difference in performance between two sampled groups.

```
Sample A
# Users response time(sec)
1900    0.541
3800    0.507
5700    0.492
7600    0.494
9500    0.514
7600    0.494
13300   0.515
16000   0.52
18000   0.554
20000   0.523

Sample B
# Users Response time(sec)
1500    4.059
3000    8.336
4500    12.362
6000    17.003
7500    19.695
8987    23.771
10487   22.369
11912   26.029
13499   25.068
```

Sample A has a list of response time like sample B. Now I want to statistically test whether or not there is a difference in response time between sample A and sample B. I checked that these samples are not normally distributed.

H0: No significant difference in response time between Sample A and sample B

Comment: Does the first line mean there were 1900 individual samples and the average response time is 0.541s? or the 1900th sample had a response time of 0.541s?

Answer (score 1):

Wilcoxon rank-sum test if the samples are not normally distributed.

Transformation seems not suitable in this case because of the small sample sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think both t-test and wilcoxon test will be ok for your data.

```
Data a;
input Group $ response;
datalines;
A    0.541
A   0.507
A    0.492
A    0.494
A   0.514
A    0.494
A   0.515
A   0.52
A   0.554
A   0.523

B    4.059
B    8.336
B    12.362
B    17.003
B    19.695
B    23.771
B   22.369
B   26.029
B   25.068
;
run;
proc ttest data=a;
class group;
var response;
run;

proc npar1way data=a wilcoxon;
class group;
var response;
run;
```

Results:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why t-test? The poster said the data can't be assumed for normal?

Comment: The student theorem says $\bar{X}$ have a $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. (Robert hogg Introduction  mathematical statistics). I think the sample size for n=10 and n=9 might be Ok enough for using CLT to assume that $\bar{X}s$ are normal distributed.

Comment: Sorry, $\bar{X} $ have a $N(\mu, \sigma^2/n)$

Comment: CLT only gives guarantees a normal for a sufficient large sample size. The question here is a small sample size. At such sample size, the distribution is less likely to be normal and violate the t-test assumption. The sample size is about 10, which is too small for a good normal approximation, in particular if the data is non-normal itself. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test#Assumptions

Comment: I think a non-parametric test is a better alternative. It'll give better power.

Comment: I think the discussion here might be helpful  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/t-test-for-non-normal-when-n50?s=2|1.0692

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24236/discussion-between-deep-north-and-student-t).