# 1 and 2 sample t-tests for plants and soils question!

Tags: r, t-test, experiment-design

I have a good friend who has an experiment where he grows different kind of plants on various soils and measures the protein content and weight each week for 5 weeks. His goal is to determine which plant yields the best protein*weight results for each soil and on which week.

The data is fairly straightforward with columns: Soil, Plant, Time(Week), Weight, Protein/g

Initially this doesn't seem like a statistics related problem as I'd just group all data by soild and find the max value of Weight*Protein from the weeks for each plant. It should give me the best Plant-Time combination for each Soil.

The issue arises when my friend also mentioned that he has to do a One sample, two sample and paired t-test on the data without much context. He has no big knowledge in statistics so he couldn't provide me any more information.

One sample t-test should be executed against a specific mean value to determine whether or not the sample was taken from a population that has a similar mean.

Two sampled and paired t-test compares 2 sample sets and determines if they are from the same population or not. Paired also makes sure to make the comparison pair-wise instead of assuming the values are randomly chosen.

The protein and weight variables are not even normally distributed, therefore a t-test is a no-go in this case.

How can I even apply the t-test to this task so I can use it to find my answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, this is a *classic* statistics problem. Your solution of just picking the maximum from each group ignores a lot of stuff (e.g. the variation in each group).

Second, not having statistics knowledge does *not* prevent your friend from giving you context.  In fact, it may even make it more likely that he can give you context without using statistical terms incorrectly.  In my work, I have often found it easier to get the context if my client knows no statistics than if he/she knows a little.

Third, the t-test isn't the best test here. I would use some sort of multilevel model to account for the repeated measures and the resulting lack of independence.  A GEE model might also be good.

Fourth, regarding normality and t-tests, see [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9573/t-test-for-non-normal-when-n50);\

Finally, if your friend *needs* to use t-tests, there are surely hypotheses that could be found for each type, e.g.

One sample: Does a particular group at a particular time point have a particular mean?

Two sample independent: Do two groups at a particular time point have the same mean?

Two sample dependent: Does a group at time 1 have the same mean as the group at time 2?

Comment: "I have often found it easier to get the context"... yes. I often have to spend time trying to get people to *stop* attempting to use statistical jargon before it's possible to figure out what they want.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. I sent you a question because I feel there are insufficient data provided as there are only one entry for each SoilType-PlantType-Week-Protein 'pair'. It seems to me that proving staitstically which SoilType-PlantType combination yields the best protein amount and on which week is impossible with just 1 experiment for each combination.