# How to test hypotheses properly?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a homepage which I would like to change in some ways. I would like to place a commercial banner on it `Ha`. In this regard, I dont want the change to affect the traffic of the original page `Ho`.

```
       I set up the hypotheses.
       I set the criteria for a decision (alpha = 0.05)
       I computed the test statistic
       And found the insignificance of `Ha`.
```

However, I just realized that rejecting the `Ha`doesnt mean I can accept `Ho`, that is there is no significant impact on the original homepage. Could someone propose how to test that properly in order to access the impact on the original page.

Comment: See also
[Distribution hypothesis testing - what is the point of doing it if you can't “accept” your null hypothesis?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/114027/17230), [Does failure to reject the null in Neyman-Pearson approach mean that one should “accept” it?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/125541/17230),
[“Accept null hypothesis” or “fail to reject the null hypothesis”?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/60670/17230), [Hypothesis testing terminology surrounding null](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14830/17230), ...

Comment: ... [If all 1000 test patients are not cured by the drug, can't we say that we accept the null hypothesis?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/158989/17230), & [Is it possible to prove a null hypothesis?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/6225/17230).