# How to calculate confidence intervals for the overlap coefficient?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

One solution for calculating the overlap coefficient for two density plots was given by @mmk here: [How to calculate overlap between empirical probability densities?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/97596/how-to-calculate-overlap-between-empirical-probability-densities/97893#97893?newreg=30acae9a2ebb46fe9bd04b3ab0810b70)

**Question:** However, does anyone know how one would calculate confidence intervals in R for the overlap coefficient, or a measure of error?

I have tried the `overlap` package  - essentially for use with time series data - but I get very different results to @mmk's code when using this package's functions. If one plots the curves, then @mmk's code seems to give a far more accurate estimate of the area of overlap.

Therefore, I would like to carry on using @mmk's code, but I do not know how to take it forward to calculate confidence intervals. How can this be done?

**Code:** Here is the code from the above link written by @mmk:

```
# simulate two samples
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100, 2)

# define limits of a common grid, adding a buffer so that tails aren't cut off
lower <- min(c(a, b)) - 1 
upper <- max(c(a, b)) + 1

# generate kernel densities
da <- density(a, from=lower, to=upper)
db <- density(b, from=lower, to=upper)
d <- data.frame(x=da$x, a=da$y, b=db$y)

# calculate intersection densities
d$w <- pmin(d$a, d$b)

# integrate areas under curves
library(sfsmisc)
total <- integrate.xy(d$x, d$a) + integrate.xy(d$x, d$b)
intersection <- integrate.xy(d$x, d$w)

# compute overlap coefficient
overlap <- 2 * intersection / total
```