# Calculate probability (area) under the overlapping area of two normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

I have two normal distributions defined by their averages and standard deviations.

Sample 1: Mean=5.28; SD=0.91

Sample 2: Mean=8.45; SD=1.36

You can see how they look like in the next image:

[image]

How can I get the probability to obtain an individual from the overlapping area (green)? Is the probability the same as the area?

Comment: What do you mean by the probability of obtaining an individual from the area?

Comment: If you sample points from either normal distribution, you get points on the Perikymata-axis rather than on the 2-dimensional area. Furthermore, the green zone is infinitely wide, so all values sampled from either distribution are under the green zone, so in this sense the probability would be 1.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala OP likely means integral over the green area.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs What would the question "Is the probability the same as the area" then mean?

Comment: @JuhoKokkala It depends. In Bayesian decision theory, this would be the irreducible error for 2 class classifier. It depends on the application.

Comment: @VladislavsDovgalecs I think you misunderstood my comment, I was not asking for an interpretation of the area but trying to parse the question. In any case, please note OP's comments to the accepted answer and a followup question posted here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103821.

Comment: You can use `overlap()` from the `overlapping` package in R. Details [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/overlapping/overlapping.pdf).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you mean by `probability to obtain an individual from the overlapping area`. This solves for the area of the green zone in your diagram:

Let:

- $X_1 \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ with pdf $f_1(x_1)$ and cdf $ F_1(x_1)$ and
- $X_2 \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$ with pdf $f_2(x_2)$ and cdf $ F_2(x_2)$,

where $\mu_1 < \mu_2$. In your example, the 'black variable' corresponds to $X_1$.

Let $c$ denote the point of intersection where the pdf's meet in the green zone of your plot Then, the area of your green intersection zone is simply:

$$P(X_1>c) + P(X_2<c) = 1 - F_1(c) + F_2(c) = 1-\frac{1}{2} \text{erf}\left(\frac{c-\mu _1}{\sqrt{2} \sigma _1}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \text{erf}\left(\frac{c-\mu _2}{\sqrt{2} \sigma _2}\right)$$

where erf(.) is the error function.

Point $c$ is the solution to $f_1(x) = f_2(x)$ within the green zone, which yields:

$$c =    \frac{\mu _2 \sigma _1^2-\sigma _2 \left(\mu _1 \sigma _2+\sigma _1 \sqrt{\left(\mu _1-\mu _2\right){}^2+2 \left(\sigma _1^2-\sigma _2^2\right) \log \left(\frac{\sigma _1}{\sigma _2}\right)}\right)}{\sigma _1^2-\sigma _2^2}$$

For your example, with $ {\mu_1 = 5.28, \mu_2 = 8.45, 
  \sigma_1 = 0.91, \sigma_2 = 1.36}$, this yields:  $c = 6.70458...$,

and the area of the green section is:  0.158413 ...

---

Comment: So this means that exists a 15.84% of overlapping among both, isn't it?

Comment: @antecessor Depends on what you mean by 'overlapping among both'. In the question you talk about some probability, but it is unclear what probabilistic interpretation the area computed here would have.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala, both normal distributions represent modern human variation of one stage of dental development (incisor in black, and molar in red). In the case of the incisor, the mean and sd represent the ages when a quarter of the root is acquired, whilst in the molar it is de mean age when the completed root is attained. So, the question to answer is, which is the probability to obtain a modern human who has both teeth in those developmental stages?

Comment: @antecessor Doesn't that probability depend on, e.g., the age distribution? Or do you mean the probability that an individual at some point in his life has both teeth in those stages? Either case, it seems that some more assumptions (correlation?) about the distributions / clarification about the question is needed. Anyway, I don't think the area of the green zone is the answer. I propose you leave this question to ask about the area of the green zone, and post a separate question about the probability you are interested in.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala Ok, I will write a new question to address the exact question.

Comment: the resolution of the equation pdf1=pdf2 yields to two solutions, so we have two intersection points, why you delete the other point @wolfies

Comment: Because, within the green zone, there is only one solution.

Comment: @wolfies mathematically, the resolution of the equation N1=N2 yields to c1=-1.2842
and c2=6.7046. According to the curve, it is true that we have only one intersection point which is positive value. But in the case that we have two points of intersection and they are both positive values. How we can compute this area ?

Comment: Please can anyone tell me where can I find the paper or any article where the equations used by @wolfies to find area under the intersection of distribution is mentioned. I need it as I have to mention this as reference in my article. Thanks

Comment: @Dev These equations are fully explained in this post.  Your request for a paper is a little bit like reading an answer that mentions 2+3+5=10 and asking for a reference to that fact.  If you must have a reference, then, why not reference this very post?

Comment: @wolfies I used this solution in my work. I need to give the reference for that in my report. Could anybody tell me the reference? Thanks, advance. I mean, where can I get that in a book or an article?

Comment: Welcome to the 21stC - the reference is:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103800/

Comment: The way I interpret the question, the green region extends across the whole line, and is the region below the pointwise minimum of both pdfs, so in relation to the log-density the situation would look sort of like this (ignoring the scales on my plot, just for the general appearance): https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaSMq.png (where there's a piece on the far left that isn't part of the required area, corresponding to where in the original diagram in the question the black curve is below the red). In most cases this will make almost no difference of course, but sometimes it does.

Comment: I think this is the point of the questions about the second intersection point; if my understanding is correct that second intersection point comes into the calculation

Comment: Is the equation for c given at the bottom of the answer correct? If both  distributions have equal variance, the equation requires dividing by zero!

Comment: @sammosummo The equation for $c$ is correct given that $\sigma_1 \neq \sigma_2$. In case of equal variances, $c=\frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}$.

Comment: this is wrong and should not be the top answer. @Mari153 is correct. There are 2 intersection points and the answer is different if you don't account for that change in shape of the overlapping area.

Comment: also there are some people asking what this area means. At least physically, this is (either exactly or closely related to) the probability that both variables are described by the same stochastic process. This is a useful quantity to have when comparing two different statistical models.

Answer (score 7):

There are two scenarios when calculating the intersections of two normal distributions. It's important to acknowledge that, in most cases, there are two intersection points:

**Equal variance**

In the modelled (or rare) examples when two normal distribution curves have ***exactly*** the same variance, there is one intersection point.  The intersection point on the abscissa axis, $(x_1)$, is calculated from:

$$x_1=\frac{\mu_a+\mu_b}{2}$$

This being, of course, the midpoint between the respective means.

**Unequal Variance**

When the two normal distribution curves intersect and have different variances, the solution to the intersection points simplifies to a quadratic form.  The consequence of the quadratic form is that there are ***always*** two intersection points $(x_1,x_2)$ on the abscissa axis.

The intersection points of the two curves can be solved algebraically to obtain the quadratic form and the roots can then be found using the quadratic formula. It’s not as hard as it seems and does not involve using the error function. However, for time and space, I give Inman and Bradley’s [version](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610928908830127) where the intersection points can be found directly.

$$(x_1,x_2)=\frac{\mu_a \sigma_b^2-\mu_b \sigma_a^2\pm\sigma_a \sigma_b \sqrt{(\mu_a-\mu_b)^2+(\sigma_b^2-\sigma_a^2)\ \ln \left(\frac{\sigma_b^2}{\sigma_a^2}\right)}}{\sigma_b^2-\sigma_a^2}$$

Where $-\infty<{x_1}<{x_2}<\infty$. (For ease of calculation, I set $\sigma_b>\sigma_a$ ).

For some intersecting normal distributions with unequal variances, the ‘second’ intersection point maybe insignificant and can, effectively, be ignored. However, for most cases – especially when $\mu_a\approx\mu_b$ – having both intersection points are critical to determine the ‘common area’ (overlap).

**Finding the Area**

The common area (overlap), $\phi$, is calculated from:

*Equal variance*
$$\phi=\min\left[\int_{-\infty}^{x_1} f(a) dx, \int_{-\infty}^{x_1} f(b) dx\right]+\min\left[\int_{x_1}^{\infty} f(a) dx, \int_{x_1}^{\infty} f(b) dx\right]$$

Where, of course, ${f(a)}=\frac{1}{\sigma_a \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-0.5 \left(\frac{x-\mu_a}{σ_a}\right)^2}$

*Unequal variance*

$$\phi=\min\left[\int_{-\infty}^{x_1} f(a) dx, \int_{-\infty}^{x_1} f(b) dx\right]+\min\left[\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(a) dx, \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f(b) dx\right]+\min\left[\int_{x_2}^{\infty} f(a) dx, \int_{x_2}^{\infty} f(b) dx\right]$$

**Answer**

Inserting the data from the question, $\mu_a=5.28, \sigma_a=0.91$ and $\mu_b=8.45, \sigma_b=1.36$, we get $x_1=-1.2842, x_2=6.7046$ and $\phi=0.1548$

**Reference:**

Inman, H.F. & Bradley Jr, E.L. (1989). The overlapping coefficient as a measure of agreement between probability distributions and point estimation of the overlap of two normal densities, Communications in Statistics - Theory and Methods, 18:10, 3851-3874, DOI: 10.1080/03610928908830127

Comment: It seems to me that you are answering a different question than that posed by the OP. The OP seeks the probability an individual is in the overlapping area (green). The curves overlap everywhere (one curve is always higher than the other), so the meaning of the question is conveyed by the diagram and the question only considers the main intersection point, closest to the mean.  You consider a different problem, with a different meaning of overlapping. Moreover, if one does a diagram of your different problem, there are multiple ways of depicting the green zone, none of which are the OPs.

Comment: @wolfies. To answer your first sentence. No I am not answering a different question. The OP question is very clear.

Comment: This is a better answer than the top one. There are indeed always 2 intersection points. The answer from wolfies correctly identifies only one of them.

Answer (score 3):

@abdelbasset,
To improve @wolfies 's answer above, there are two intersection points c, let's call them c1 and c2. Here, c1=-1.2848 and c2=6.7046. @wolfies ignored c1 (it likely will be too far in the tails of the probability density functions to matter (especially if we round to just a few decimal points)).

The more correct way is to find both c1 and c2, and to find the area of overlap of both functions: 
AREA OF OVERLAP = P(X1 > j1) + P(X2 < j1) - [P(X2 < j2)-P(X1 < j2)]

therefore, using cdf's
AREA OF OVERLAP = 1 - F1(j1,μ2,σ2)+F2(j1,μ2,σ2)-F2(j2,μ2,σ2)+F1(j2,μ1,σ1)

Comment: Welcome to the site, @luckapani. You cannot use the "Your Answer" field to comment or respond to comments. As a result, this would be deleted. However, there is the core of an answer here. Can you edit your post to make it more of an answer & not a comment? Since you're new here, you may want to take our [tour], which contains information for new users.

Answer (score 0):

Normalise the graphs to an area of 1 by dividing each by their respective standard deviation. Then use simple subtraction from a z-graph to calculate the probability of an occurrance in that overlap area. No need for erfs.

Comment: i assume that he means that he wants to compute the probability in the green region. That can be done simply by adding the area in the right tail of the first distribution to the ares in the left tail of the second distribution. There is no normalization necessary.

Comment: The separate normalization of the two graphs will change the overlap area unless they have identical SDs.  Thus, this answer is generally wrong.