# How do I calculate the Jaccard distance for normal distributions?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, jaccard-similarity

I'm trying to replicate the results in this [paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgkKS.png). I'm stuck at this part:[image] specifically,

```
calculate Jaccard intersection of pdata1 & pdata2
```

Is there some neat formula for calculating the Jaccard index of two normal distributions given their parameters?

I found this on Wikipedia, for the generalized Jaccard distance:

Or more simply, is there an easy trick to calculate the intersection and the union of two normal distributions given their parameters

[image: [1]: https://www.researchgate.net/]publication/304187762_Human_Activity_Recognition_in_AAL_Environments_Using_Random_Projections

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Jaccard distance."  There is a Jaccard *index* that is meaningful for two finite datasets, as indicated in the algorithm, but it's unclear how that would generalize to "normal distributions" and it isn't at all evident how it would be applicable to this algorithm anyway.

Comment: `As a criterion for estimating the mapping, we use the Jaccard distance metric between two probability density estimates of data points representing each class.`

Comment: The author uses Jaccard distance to mean Jaccard index. They're using random projections for coming up with a kernel density estimation given the data points and then calculating the Jaccard index. I don't see why Jaccard index cannot be applied to continuous distributions, the formula seems general enough.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), the Jaccard index "measures similarity between finite sample sets".  Please explain in what possible sense a *normal distribution* could be considered a *finite sample set*!

Comment: According to Wikipedia, it can be generalized to probability measures.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  Since $$\int\max(f,g)d\mu + \int\min(f,g)d\mu = \int(f+g)d\mu = 1+1 = 2,$$ your formula is equivalent to $$J(f,g) = \frac{\int\min(f,g)d\mu}{2 - \int\min(f,g)d\mu},$$ reducing the question to finding this one integral.  That is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103800/. I suspect it might also be answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12209, but be cautious--not a single one of those answers actually states what it is computing! (The best does have a suggestive figure.)