# Defining the overlapping area of two log-normal distributions with different means, same variance, and different scaling factors that add up to 1

Tags: density-function, lognormal-distribution, finite-mixture-model

Define
$$
\begin{cases}
X_1\sim Lognormal(ln(\mu_1), \sigma^2) \\
X_2\sim Lognormal(ln(\mu_2), \sigma^2)
\end{cases}
$$
where $\mu_2>\mu_1>0$ and that there is a definite proportion, $\eta\in(0,1)$,  between $X_1$ and $X_2$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
f_1(x)=\frac{\eta}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-{\frac{(ln(x)-ln(\mu_1))^2 \,\,\,\,\,\,}{2\sigma^2}}} \\
f_2(x)=\frac{1-\eta}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(ln(x)-ln(\mu_2))^2 \,\,\,\,\,\,}{2\sigma^2}}
\end{cases}
$$
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ represent the $\eta$-scaled PDF's of $X_1$ and $X_2$, respectively.

Based on the above definitions, note that $\int_{x=0}^\infty f_1(x)\,dx\,+\int_{x=0}^\infty f_2(x)\,dx=1$.

---

Given $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$, $\sigma$, and $\eta$, how is the overlapping area of the two probability distribution curves, $OVL=f(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma,\eta)$, defined?

Please see a illustrative plot below, where $OVL=f(\mu_1=5,\mu_2=10,\sigma=20\%,\eta=50\%)$ is highlighted in yellow:

[image: Plotting]

I am able to perform numerical approximation for $OVL$ using the trapezoidal rule, but I need to express $OVL$ explicitly and I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: Related [Percentage of overlapping regions of two normal distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/percentage-of-overlapping-regions-of-two-normal-distributions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: [Calculate probability (area) under the overlapping area of two normal distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/103800/calculate-probability-area-under-the-overlapping-area-of-two-normal-distributi)

Comment: Thanks. I have seen these, but they refer to normal distributions and also do not have the proportion parameter defined in my question.

Comment: What statistical meaning do you suppose the yellow area to have?  (I cannot recognize any -- and it is not equivalent to any function of your $f_1$ and $f_2.$)  What is the function $f$ you want to integrate??

Comment: @whuber $OVL$ that I quoted in my question is something called the _overlapping coefficient_, whose converse (i.e. $1-OVL$) has been used as a disparity index to associate with the estimation quality of a mixture of two normal distributions (I will put relevant papers in the next comment). These work and those suggested by user2974951 are for normal but not log-normal distributions. $f_1$ (the red curve) and $f_2$ (the green curve) is the pdf of the log-normal distribution. I am guessing I need and I am trying to solve for the intersections first, but my algebraic skill is not that good...

Comment: @whuber Lourens, S., Zhang, Y., Long, J. D., & Paulsen, J. S. (2013). Bias in Estimation of a Mixture of Normal Distributions. Journal of biometrics and biostatistics, 4, 1000179.
Lourens et al in turn cited this:
Henry F. Inman & Edwin L. Bradley Jr (1989) The overlapping coefficient as a measure of agreement between probability distributions and point estimation of the overlap of two normal densities, Communications in Statistics - Theory and Methods, 18:10, 3851-3874

Comment: Thank you for the references.  The problem is that OVL does not transform meaningfully when you analyze the distribution of $\exp(X)$ (the lognormal distribution) rather than $X$ itself (the normal distribution), so we're stuck right at the beginning: what do you hope this "overlapping area" represents?

Comment: @whuber According to the data from Lourens et al, ML-based estimation of bimodal normal mixture shows systematic biases, including negative biases for $\mu_1$ and $\sigma$, and positive biases for $\mu_2$ etc., which are worse with larger true $OVL$. We are not working on normal mixtures. Our work involves an MLE process of a Bayesian hierarchical model that involves the estimation of multiple parameters, including a log-normally distributed parameter of interest which consists of a mixture as described in the question. We want to describe numerically how $OVL$ relate with biases in our case.

Comment: Btw, I seem to have managed to show that $\exists!\tau\in\mathbb{R}^+:f_1(\tau)=f_2(\tau)$. I think solution to the question itself will follows

Comment: That is correct.  In general, though, take a little bit of care: that's true only because both of your lognormal distributions have a common log sd.  Otherwise, there are two solutions.  (The problem is easily reduced to intersecting two parabolas.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from a friend we solved the problem ourselves:

Let $\{\tau\in\Bbb{R}^+|f_1(\tau,\mu_1,\sigma,\eta)=f_2(\tau,\mu_2,\sigma,\eta)\}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\eta}{\tau\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(\ln\tau-\ln{\mu_1})^2}{2\sigma^2}}&=\frac{1-\eta}{\tau\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(\ln\tau-\ln{\mu_2})^2}{2\sigma^2}} \\
e^\frac{(\ln\tau-\ln{\mu_1})^2-(\ln\tau-\ln{\mu_2})^2}{2\sigma^2}&=\frac{\eta}{1-\eta}\quad (\because\tau>0) \\
\frac{2\ln\tau\ln{\tau_2}-2\ln\tau\ln{\tau_1}+(\ln{\mu_1})^2-(\ln{\mu_2})^2}{2\sigma^2}&=\ln\frac{\eta}{1-\eta} \\
\ln\tau&=\frac{\sigma^2[\ln\eta-\ln(1-\eta)]}{\ln{\mu_2}-\ln{\mu_1}}+\frac{\ln{\mu_2}+\ln{\mu_1}}{2} \\
\tau&=e^{\frac{\sigma^2[\ln\eta-\ln(1-\eta)]}{\ln{\mu_2}-\ln{\mu_1}}+\frac{\ln{\mu_2}+\ln{\mu_1}}{2}}
\end{align}
$$
Since $\mu_2>\mu_1$ and $\eta\in(0,1)$, $\exists!\tau\in\Bbb{R}^+|f_1=f_2$

---

$\forall x\in\Bbb{R}^+$,

$\ln{f_2(x,\mu_2,\sigma,\eta)}-\ln{f_1(x,\mu_1,\sigma,\eta)}$

$=\ln\frac{1-\eta}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}-\ln\frac{\eta}{x\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}+\frac{(\ln{x}-\ln{\mu_1})^2}{2\sigma^2}-\frac{(\ln{x}-\ln{\mu_2})^2}{2\sigma^2}$

$=\ln\frac{1-\eta}{\eta}+\frac{(\ln{\mu_1})^2-(\ln{\mu_2})^2}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{\ln{\mu_2}-\ln{\mu_1}}{\sigma^2}\ln{x}$, which is strictly increasing on $x\quad(\because\mu_2>\mu_1)$

$\therefore\frac{f_2(x,\mu_2,\sigma,\eta)}{f_1(x,\mu_1,\sigma,\eta)}$ is strictly increasing on $x$

It follows that:

$\begin{cases}
f_2(x,\mu_2,\sigma,\eta)>f_1(x,\mu_1,\sigma,\eta)\quad\forall x>\tau \\
f_2(x,\mu_2,\sigma,\eta)<f_1(x,\mu_1,\sigma,\eta)\quad\forall x<\tau
\end{cases}\quad\quad\ldots\ldots(*)$

---

The $\eta$-scaled CDF's of $X_1$ and $X_2$, denoted as $F_1$ and $F_2$, are defined as follows:
$\begin{cases}
F_1(x,\mu_1,\sigma,\eta)=\frac{\eta}{2}[1+erf(\frac{\ln{x}-\ln{\mu_1}}{\sqrt{2}\sigma})] \\
F_2(x,\mu_2,\sigma,\eta)=\frac{1-\eta}{2}[1+erf(\frac{\ln{x}-\ln{\mu_2}}{\sqrt{2}\sigma})]
\end{cases}$, where $erf(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt\pi}\int_0^z{e^{-t^2}dt}$

By (*),

$\begin{align}
OVL=f(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma,\eta)&=F_2(\tau,\mu_2,\sigma,\eta)+[1-F_1(\tau,\mu_1,\sigma,\eta)] \\
&=1+F_2(\tau,\mu_2,\sigma,\eta)-F_1(\tau,\mu_1,\sigma,\eta)
\end{align}$