# Estimating prevalence of an effect in a RCT study using the overlapping coefficient (and does chocolate make your acne worse?)

Tags: probability, coefficient-of-variation, controlling-for-a-variable

I'm trying to tease out prevalence of effects seen from controlled studies, e.g. what % of people would expect to see a higher acne lesion count if consuming 6 oz of cocoa / day? The average effect is clear, but the distribution of the data is not.

One such study is "Double-blind, Placebo-controlled Study Assessing the Effect of Chocolate Consumption in Subjects with a History of Acne Vulgaris" and here's their result:

[image]

It looks like the error bars are reporting Standard Error of the Mean = ~2, n = 13 subjects, r = 0.250 at 4 weeks.

My question is, can you based on this data, give an estimate for what % of people would be expected to see an increase in lesion count by consuming said amount of coca/day for 4 days?

Could you calculate the "overlapping coefficient" of the result (discussed here: [Percentage of overlapping regions of two normal distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/percentage-of-overlapping-regions-of-two-normal-distributions)) and if, would that be a good answer?

Comment: The information there doesn't address the proportion of people with an increase in lesion count, only that the average number of lesions increased - it could happen that the proportion experiencing an increase was 0%, or 100% or anything in between. It's even possible *fewer* people had lesions while the mean number of lesions increased. To estimate that from this information would require some assumptions; I can't make your assumptions for you.

Comment: Thanks Glen, so to me assuming a normal distribution would make most sense in lieu of the full dataset (which I could conceivably get in some, but not all cases).

Comment: A normal distribution of what, exactly? The proportion of people with lesions? Why would (count) proportions be normal? What about heterogeneity - i.e. that people will tend to respond differently for different  groups (we're not genetically identical, other parts of our diet differ, ages differ, activity levels differ), so even if we were - *ceteris paribus* - broadly similar in responses, in practice the *ceteris* is not *paribus*. The RCT will remove the mean effect of such factors, but you'd need to rely on them occurring in such a way that the mixture distribution was still normal.

Comment: I would count proportions to be normal because I believe that a normal distribution is more the most likely one. Since this is part of aggregating and integrating results of several studies, doing that seems fair. But I'm not a statistician and could be totally wrong. 

I'm trying to make sense of dozens of studies of systemic factors influencing skin disease in this way to be published in a free web page/app form, similar to what examine.com has done for supplements. And ideally I'd want to say something about prevalence of the effect and not just report its average :)