# How to compute the normalized overlap area between two curves

Tags: r, python, ggplot2, matplotlib, overlapping-data

I am trying to calculate the overlap area (normalized by the total area) of two plots. The plots are from X Y datasets.

I saw a lot of questions about getting the overlap area but from normal distributions([Percentage of overlapping regions of two normal distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/percentage-of-overlapping-regions-of-two-normal-distributions))

data1
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwQ2EnAgefKRZV9lQjZKbDJIY0k

data2
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwQ2EnAgefKRdEhBSGlrcG9VM3M

Comment: The thread you reference contains a general solution.  You only need to replace the analytic integration function `integrate` with a numeric integration function of your choosing.