# Why is the Kolmogorov–Smirnov (KS) test more popular than the Overlapping Coefficient (OVL)?

Tags: density-function, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, similarities

The Overlapping Coefficient (OVL) measures the common area between two Probability Density Functions (see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/percentage-of-overlapping-regions-of-two-normal-distributions) question for more details). Intuitively, this seems like a good way to gauge the similarity between two distributions; and perhaps even more useful than the Kolmogorov–Smirnov (KS) test which will penalise based on the maximum vertical distance between two Cumulative Distribution Functions while ignoring all other differences between the two distributions at other points.

Is there any reason why my colleagues all know of the KS test but OVL is hardly spoken of, or why I often find the KS test in the literature and not OVL? I'm even struggling to find a Python function that calculates OVL. And why when I read up on [Goodness of Fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) tests on Wikipedia, there is also no mention of OVL?

Comment: KS Test is a statistical test while OVL is just a measure. You don't get p-value from OVL.

Comment: @SmallChess  That could be a good reason to use OVL.  P values from KS are pretty senseless.

Comment: @PeterFlom Maybe. But that would mean some random cutoffs for different distributions. No benchmark to against. How would you quantify exactly what is significant from random noise, and what isn't?

Comment: Using a p-value is also arbitrary.  At least, with OVL, there is an intuition about what is being measured.

Comment: To my understanding, OVL is for two normal distributions but KS-Test is a general test.

Comment: Oliver, although an overlap integral could make sense for comparing two *theoretical* densities, it is extremely rare to measure a density directly: all we have is data.  How exactly do you propose to convert two datasets into an overlap integral of density functions?  You're going to need some strong assumptions and arbitrary choices, at the very least.  What, then, do you really mean by "OVL" as a statistical test?

Comment: @whuber, you would have to select n, being the number of bins. [This](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2007GL032834/abstract) paper, first applies kernel smoothing (KDE) to the data, and then calculates the sum of the minimum height between both densities at each bin (see equation 1). So yes, with the KS test statistic one does not need to decide how many bins to use.