# How to differentiate statistically between two numerical continuous datasets?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, data-visualization, inference, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

[image]

Sample from:
Green - Gamma(45, 1); Red - Normal(375, 19)

These two samples clearly come from two different distributions. Is it possible to verify that these two samples come from two different distributions by comparing different statistics of the distributions like mean, variance, Interquartile Range, Kurtosis, Skewness?

Currently, I am using the Two-Sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test for this problem but it is not giving satisfactory results when the distribution plot overlaps.

[image]

Sample from:
Green - Gamma(45, 1); Red - Normal(45, 6.2)

Two Sample KS Test Results:
For Picture 1 - (statistic=1.0, pvalue=0.0)
For Picture 2 (Overlapping distributions) - (statistic=0.026, pvalue=0.0)

Comment: Can you show us what the two distributions you're trying to compare look like? What is not satisfactory about the result?

Comment: Edited in the post, included the KS Test results.

Comment: Both KS tests give a p-value of effectively zero, which indicates one would reject the null hypothesis (that the samples come from the same distribution) for both pairs of distributions. Is that a typo? If not, it will help potential answers to spell out what you feel unsatisfactory on the KS test results on the (more) overlapping distributions.

Comment: @mathematician in light of the p-value being effectively $0$ (hence conclude that the distributions *are* different) is this a case of practical vs statistical significance?  Although there is a genuine statistical difference between the two distributions, would it matter in the real world which one was used? https://www.statology.org/statistical-practical-significance/

Comment: The KS Test values are correct. The problem is when I compare Normal(45, 6) with Normal(46,6) it gives (statistic=0.02, pvalue=0.0) but the distributions are almost similar. The statistic is low because these distribution overlaps.

Comment: @jcken, actually I am trying to validate the dataset for machine learning model drift. In the above example, though there is not much statistical difference, I want to at least validate that Normal(45,6) vs Normal(46,6) are more similar compare to Gamma(45,1) vs Normal(45,6). The KS test for both these comparison gives almost similar results.

Comment: @Mathematician That an irrelevant difference is reported as "statistically significant" typically occurs when the sample size is very large: you can make the tiniest difference "significant" simply by increasing the sample size. Can this be the case in your example?

Comment: @cdalitz Yes, I also thought so since I am doing the test for 3.2 million records. That's why I wanted to switch to test-statistics (mean, variance, skewness, interquartile-range, kurtosis) to compare distributions, but I was not sure how much variation in test statistics should I allow to detect whether the two distributions are similar?

Comment: What is your definition of two distributions being similar (or different)? Do they have to be from the same family? A 99%+ overlap? Or something else? Without this it will be difficult to proceed.

Comment: By similar distribution I mean, if you put the pdfs of the two distributions on top of each other and if they have an overlap of more than 95%. By putting on top of each other I mean Normal(45, 6) and Normal(345,6) should be considered similar since when the cartesian origin for Normal(345,6) is shifted to have its mean aligned to 45, they will have 100% overlap.

Comment: Your problem is now substantially different from what you originally posted (as least to me). Not sure if the answers to this question helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/percentage-of-overlapping-regions-of-two-normal-distributions

Comment: Yes, I kind of built a better understanding after this discussion. This seems to solve the problem at least for two samples from the normal distribution. I will try to improve the code to include comparisons for different distributions.

Answer (score 2):

After some discussion in the comments, it seems that @Mathematician would like to measure how similar pairs of distributions are.

Let $Y \sim N(45, 6)$, $X_1 \sim N(46, 6)$ and $X_2 \sim Gamma(45, 1)$

One of the most common ways to do this is to this is via Kullback-Liebler divergences. We can see which of $KL(X_1 || Y), KL(X_2 || Y)$ is smallest. The smallest KL suggests the better approximation. Since $Y$, $X_1$ are Normals, it is simple to calculate $KL(X_1 || Y) = 0.083$ (3dp).

A Monte Carlo estimate (I am too lazy to calculate the integral!) of $KL(X_2 || Y)$ is $KL(X_2 || Y) \approx 2$, thus the better "approximation" to $Y$ is $X_1$