# Controlling type II error with multiple comparisons

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, equivalence

I am confused about how to perform correction for multiple comparisons in the case where I do not want to reject the null hypothesis.

I am doing multiple ANOVAs where I would like to show that there is no significant differences across groups. Having multiple comparisons, I would like to adjust the outcome of the test. However, typical methods are designed for controlling type-I errors (accidentally rejecting `H0` when it is true), but what I care about in this case is type-II error (accidentally accepting `H0` when it is false).

My question is twofold:

1. Does my statistical design even make sense? (Do you ever design a test where you actually do not want to reject the null hypothesis?)
2. If yes, how should I adjust the outcome of my test for multiple comparisons if I aim at controlling type-II errors?

It seems that [equivalence testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3038/how-to-test-hypothesis-of-no-group-differences) might be the way to tackle both of the issues, but having never used it, I am not sure how to apply it to multiple groups, or if it even is the best way to go.

Comment: There is a type of clinical trial called "non-inferiority" where the goal is to show that outcomes from a novel treatment are not worse than the standard-of-care treatment (which is currently reimbursed by insurance/medicaid).   Essentially you are showing that outcomes are not better (statistically significantly different) but rather are not different.   These are done when the new treatment costs less, or consumes less time & effort (nurses, post-op care, etc).  Thus, looking at non-inferiority tests may be a gateway for what you're after.