# When should one use the Welch's T-test?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I want to test whether the mean in two samples are different. I don't know their variance and estimate them from the sample. When should I use the Welch-Satterthwaite approximation to the degrees of freedom for the test statistic?

Comment: The Welch approach deals with the case where the variances are unknown and expected to be very different. This is the famous Behrens-Fisher problem.

Answer (score 0):

Welch's t-test does not assume equal variances for the two groups.

Some people argue that Welch's t-test should be used by default.  For an example, see the article [at this link](https://www.rips-irsp.com/articles/10.5334/irsp.82/).

Also note that R uses Welch's *t-test* as the default for the t.test function.  I believe SAS output for PROC TTEST returns both the Student t, and Welch's t ("Satterthwaite").  [See Wikipedia for other software implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test).

For a more complete discussion, [see this thread on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305/when-conducting-a-t-test-why-would-one-prefer-to-assume-or-test-for-equal-vari)